# Accessing an Objects values Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Okay so I'm creating a `simple` flight booking system. I've spent a fair bit of time debugging and now even the simplest things are stumping me.

I have an interface which looks close to:

```
public class Flight implements IFlight {

String destination;
String departure;
int clubrows = 0;
int ecorows = 0;

public Flight(String dest, String dept, int clubrow, int ecorow) {
    destination = dest;
    departure = dept;
    clubrows = clubrow;
    ecorows = ecorow;


}


public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}
```

This class has many similar get methods.
Now i'm trying to write a for loop where every value that is put in is printed out. So i need to access all the 0 values then all the 1 values etc.
it looks kinda like this right now:

```
public void flightManifest() { 
    System.out.println("Available flights: ");
    for(int i=0; i<flightCount ;i++){
        System.out.println("Flight number: "+flightCount  +", Destination: "+  +", Departure time: "+  );
    }
```

So essentially whenever i try to access the variables i keep balls-ing it up, so how am i meant to access these values each time round?

So the way I store them is as such:
        flightArr[flightCount] = new Flight (dest, dept, clubrow, ecorow);
        flightCount++;
or at least thats how it is made.

Comment: Show us how you're storing your list/array of flights.

Comment: Your `Flight` class should have private fields. Use `getXX()` methods to access the values. There is also no need to set `int` values to `0` unless you have a constructor that doesn't assign them values.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `toString()` method to your `Flight` class, and then simply call it within your loop.

Within that `toString()` method, return the String concatenation of your class fields. That's all.

Comment: You might want to call this method  toFlightInfoString() or some such.  That way of you have a couple of other different formats you can add them later.